# Что тут означает v24?

Tags: android-studio

Я думаю у меня простой вопрос, что тут значит v24?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это значит, что ваш файл лежит в папке

```
res/drawable-v24
```

Это, в свою очередь, значит, что файл будет использован приложением только для `API>=24`. Т.е. на ОС 5 версии этого файла приложение видеть не будет. Если вы не поместите файл с таким же названием в папку `res/drawable` и попытаетесь его в коде использовать, то получите `ResourceNotFoundException`