# Почему в CollapsingToolbarLayout ошибка?

Tags: java, android

На Android ниже 7.0 закрывается приложение. Пишет ошибку. Использую новую библиотеку Androidx. Recycler_fon - это стиль с закругленными углами.
Может быть такое, что Android 5.1, 6.0 не поддерживают Androidx?

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

activity_main

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        style="@style/Recycler_fon"
        app:contentScrim="@color/black"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Mol_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/Mol"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UPC_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/Mol_text"
                android:text="@string/UPC"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/kiev"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.pl.prayerbook/ua.pl.prayerbook.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at ua.pl.prayerbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at ua.pl.prayerbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "ua.pl.prayerbook:drawable/myfon_2" (7f080081)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080081 a=2 r=0x7f080081}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:155)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите скрин со структурой папок/файлов ресурсов, чтобы стало ясно где у вас лежит файл `myfon_2`. Скорее всего он просто не в той папке лежит.

Comment: Я новичек. А где он должен лежать?

Comment: Написал в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы положили ваш ресурс не в ту папку.

Вам надо переключить отображение проекта с `Android` на `Project` и переместить ваш файл из `res/drawable-v24` в `res/drawable`. Это можно узнать из сообщения об ошибке + из подсказки в IDEA так: [Что тут означает v24?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012186/17609)

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, так просто. Правда у меня теперь ругается на стили. Сейчас попробую поправить там.

Comment: СПАСИБО заработало, это так просто. Вот что значит уметь читать английский. :))))