# Ошибка при запуске приложения на 6.0 и более ранних версиях андройд

Tags: android, исключения

Программа работает только в версиях выше 6. Вылетает прямо на стартовом лейауте Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем дело.
Лог:

```
11-05 02:13:47.210 21713-21713/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mersel.android.minefield, PID: 21713
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mersel.android.minefield/com.mersel.android.minefield.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.mersel.android.minefield.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.mersel.android.minefield.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.mersel.android.minefield.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.mersel.android.minefield:drawable/background_menu" (7f06005a) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005a a=-1 r=0x7f06005a}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2646)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:388)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:570)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:566)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:573)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.mersel.android.minefield.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

В макете использую тег:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Библиотеки в build.gradle попробовал все возможные, включая альфа и бетта версии.

В gradle.properties установлены:

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: У вас проблема не нахождения ресурса. Это видно из строки лога `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.mersel.android.minefield:drawable/background_menu"`. Скорее всего картинка не в той папке находится. Чтобы исправить - смотрите ответ тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1034143/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-collapsingtoolbarlayout-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0/1034275#1034275

Comment: Да, вы правы. Проблема решена. Спасибо!